# How to implement Many to many relation in django when the relation contain attributes?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, uml

I'm begginer at django and I knew that you can use ManyToManyField to link two models like author-post user-groups. 
so I have this relation in my UML [image: UML Example]

How can I implement this in my code ?
my shot was like this

```
class User(models.Model):
# user fields

class Group(models.Model):
     # group fields

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_index=True)
    IsAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Est un admin')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("group", "user"),)
```

I want to use ManyToManyFields so I can refer between them (if I haven't IsAdmin field, I don't have to create the third class 'GroupMember')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the example from the official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

> The intermediate model is associated with the ManyToManyField using
>   the **through** argument to point to the model that will act as an
>   intermediary.

The Group class in your model should be like:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    # group fields
    # ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')
```